# apt-get install gives 404 not found, but URL works

Tags: apt

I am trying to set up an [apt repository](http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/).

This repository is actually replacing one that already exists and is functioning fine. I can't manage to install a package from this repo.

In my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I have the line:

```
deb http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386 /
```

An `apt-get update` goes through perfectly fine.
But then something like `apt-get install appliance50` (a package in that repo) gives me:

```
Err http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/  appliance50 2014-0
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/./appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

But then copying that URL into a browser downloads the file just fine! Is there some fundamental step that I'm missing? Does it have to do something with the fact that this server is redirecting the request to S3?

Edit:

Here's the output of "sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::Http=true install appliance50", per the comment:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::Http=true install appliance50
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb cifs-utils dmraid dpkg-repack
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 kpartx kpartx-boot libdebian-installer4
  libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 libldb1 libntdb1 libtalloc2
  libtevent0 libtimezonemap1 libwbclient0 localechooser-data lvm2 lzma
  python-crypto python-ldb python-ntdb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb
  python3-icu python3-pam rdate samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs
  watershed
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  appliance50
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,096 B of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Working]GET /appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/./appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.cs50.net
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 14:23:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=27CBB9F102866AACDE415904FB505399868B9DB4E22AC5183099E4BEEC583EF1DFA3B6E45DCB1D708481F98DC786A644C763A900F7898475BA865AD219D4E4F1F157545837;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

Err http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/  appliance50 2014-0
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs50.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/./appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire `sudo apt-get -o Debug::Acquire::Http=true install appliance50`

Comment: You've got a redirect in there. I get a http 302 code. I don't know how well apt handles redirects. This was supposedly fixed in 2008, see https://bugs.debian.org/479350 but maybe try without the redirect?

Comment: Edited above to include the output of that command!

Comment: is there a relation among http://mirror.cs50.net and https://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net? because using web browser the package come from https://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net. So, can be a symbolic link?

Comment: There is a relation that I'm not 100% clear on. I think it's part of the bridge between the request and getting the file from S3. If I replace "mirror.cs50.net" with "blah.cloudfront.net" in /etc/apt/sources.list, the behavior is the same.

I can inquire as to the relation if helpful.

Comment: @RobBowden Filing an apt bug report would be a good idea at this point. You could include a link to this question. OF course, for that to work, you will have to leave your setup alone. Or create a dummy setup which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Bug report submitted: https://bugs.debian.org/757039

Comment: @RobBowden Feel free to add to the report. You can update by emailing 757039@bugs.debian.org.

Comment: Thank you! It would've taken me a bit to figure out how to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug on `apt-get`, that is not sending the correct GET headers, so the server answers with 404.

For example, telnet to the server `mirror.cs50.net` at port 80 (HTTP), and enter the following (emulating an apt-get request):

```
GET /appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/./appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)
Host: mirror.cs50.net
Accept: */*
```

Then you will see the following:

```
telnet mirror.cs50.net 80
Trying 54.84.6.206...
Connected to mirror.cs50.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/./appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)
Host: mirror.cs50.net
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 18:31:01 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=27CBB9F102866AACDE415904FB505399868B9DB4E22AC5183099E4BEEC583EF1DFA3B6E45DFCB95EFBFF7B8F8F555126DCFFF8A461898475BA865AD219D4E4F1F157545837;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

If we leave out the dot (`/./`) in the GET request, then the request responds with a redirect, i.e. 302, which is correct.

```
GET /appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.cs50.net
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 19:03:27 GMT
Location: http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/appliance50/2014/debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/appliance50_2014-0_i386.deb
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: AWSELB=27CBB9F102866AACDE415904FB505399868B9DB4E22AC5183099E4BEEC583EF1DFA3B6E45DFCB95EFBFF7B8F8F555126DCFFF8A461898475BA865AD219D4E4F1F157545837;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=3600
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

I've checkd this out with other mirrors and they report the same:

```
Trying 64.50.233.100...
Connected to ftp-nyc.osuosl.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /debian/pool/main/e/./efivar_0.10-5_i386.deb HTTP/1.1         
Host: ftp-nyc.osuosl.org
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.6)

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 18:47:03 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 307
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /debian/pool/main/e/efivar_0.10-5_i386.deb was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at ftp-nyc.osuosl.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

You should include in your bug report that apt-get should strip the get headers of the dot-n-slash.

Comment: So much time spent on this. Thanks so much!